# ASP.NET C# Changing connection strings based on drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, dropdown

I'm still very new to ASP.Net C#, I have this piece of code which works fine. I have multiple connection strings in the web.config file and I switch between them based on the text of my drop down list. I was hoping for some advice of any neater/cleaner method to archive this rather than what I have below (if there is). Thanks!

```
 protected void search_ClickALL(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text == "ENWL")
    {
        using (
       SqlConnection conn =
           new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConHprENWL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dpCreatedDT, enStatusCH, enNotificationNoNI FROM dp_enquiry WHERE ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);
            try
            {
                SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
                search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
                search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
                gridviewALL.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Job Number not found!');</script>");
                }
                conn.Close();
                mpePopUpALL.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    else if (ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text == "NW")
    {
        using (
       SqlConnection conn =
           new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConHprNorthumbrian"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dpCreatedDT, enStatusCH, enNotificationNoNI FROM dp_enquiry WHERE ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);
            try
            {
                SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
                search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
                search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
                gridviewALL.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Job Number not found!');</script>");
                }
                conn.Close();
                mpePopUpALL.Show();
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate function and write all your business logic inside it and get the connection string as parameter based on drop down item

```
protected void search_ClickALL(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text == "ENWL")
    {
        ShowData(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConHprENWL"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    }
    else if (ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text == "NW")
    {
        ShowData(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConHprNorthumbrian"].ConnectionString).ToString());
    }
}

private void ShowData(string connectionstring)
{
    using (
       SqlConnection conn =
           new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dpCreatedDT, enStatusCH, enNotificationNoNI FROM dp_enquiry WHERE ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);
            try
            {
                SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
                search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
                search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
                gridviewALL.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Job Number not found!');</script>");
                }
                conn.Close();
                mpePopUpALL.Show();
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @LiranBo: `ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text` may not be same as `ConnectionStrings` key. They can be different look closely in OP post the text is **ENWL** but connection string key is **ConHprENWL** different.

Comment: In order to use `ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text` you must have exactly same name both in dropdown text and connection string key in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the same code multipule time can make it in once by a [Switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/06tc147t.aspx) case

```
     string ConnectionString;
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConHprENWL"].ConnectionString
                break;
            case 1:
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZ"].ConnectionString
                break;

        }
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Con.Open();  
/*YOUR CODE */
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the following operation twice:

```
       conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dpCreatedDT, enStatusCH, enNotificationNoNI FROM dp_enquiry WHERE ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);

 try
        {
            SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
            search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
            search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
            gridviewALL.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Job Number not found!');</script>");
            }
            conn.Close();
            mpePopUpALL.Show();
        }
```

instead make it as a function and pass your SQLConnection conn to the function as an argument.

also when you are using using statement, you don't need to close conn.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just use the if to just choose the connection string, cause the rest seems the same.

```
protected void search_ClickALL(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ddlALL.SelectedItem.Text].ConnectionString))
 {
     conn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dpCreatedDT, enStatusCH, enNotificationNoNI FROM dp_enquiry WHERE ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);
     try
     {
         SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
         search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
         search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
         cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
         SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(dr);
         gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
         gridviewALL.DataBind();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Response.Write(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
         {
             Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Job Number not found!');</script>");
         }
         conn.Close();
         mpePopUpALL.Show();
     }
  }

}
```